# "Can't find camera" on local machine triggered from OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, opencv, webcam

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-6179nsls/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (880) open VIDEOIO(V4L2): can't find camera device
```

I'am getting this error while trying to access my webcam
I've also tried parameters 0 and -1 in the method cv2.VideoCapture() method as they seem to work in some cases.
Is there any way to access the webcam?

Comment: You don't access the webcam of the user, but of the *server*. In order to open the camera at the user side, you need some JavaScript.

Comment: Which kind of some javascript? kindly share any reff. if you have

Answer (score 0):

Check if your code consists of more than one cv2.VideoCapture(0).You won't be able to run the flask server in debug mode because it calls cv2.VideoCapture(0) more than one time.

Comment: No,
I've used it only once.

Comment: Are you using Linux

Comment: and also if you are using anaconda you need to install these 2 packages also

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge opencv

Comment: I'm using python3 on WSL.

Comment: If you resolved the problem please accept my answer